# Purpose of /net directory

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, fhs, net

I notice on my system (Manjaro Linux) that:

1. I have an empty directory named `/net`
2. This directory  is not mentioned in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

What is the intention behind this directory (quoting chapter and verse)?

---

Is it like `/mnt` ([which is for temporary mounts](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MNTMOUNTPOINTFORATEMPORARILYMOUNT)) but for network (eg `sshfs`, `nfs`) mountpoints?

Or, in other words, is it like `/media`, but for non-removable non-temporary mount points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is very similar to `/mnt` and is designed to contain `nfs` shared directories from remote hosts.

If there is a NFS server named `nfsserver` sharing a directory named `shared-directory`, you can access it just by listing or reading files in `/net/nfsserver/shared-directory[/filepath]`.

This featured is provided by the [automounter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter), was first implemented by Sun Microsystems in SunOS 4 (1988).

Unlike Linux, Solaris is documenting it in its file system hierarchy standard documentation:

```
$ man filesystem
...
/net

   Temporary mount point for file systems that are  mounted
   by the automounter.
```

Note that the /net directory is not hardcoded and you can select a different one by editing the `/etc/auto.master` or `/etc/autofs/auto.master` configuration file. See for example this [documentation page](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book.opensuse.reference/cha.autofs.html#sec.autofs.advanced).

Note also that the same mechanism can be used to automount CIFS or fuse based (e.g. sshfs) file systems shares. See this [Gentoo wiki page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AutoFS#Simple_Windows-like_Samba_share_mounting) or that [Ubuntu documentation one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs).

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes but `amd` standard configuration is to mount on `/a`, not `/net` which is `autofs` standard mount point. I assume the OP machine is running `autofs`, not `amd`.

Comment: Thanks, I've not played with autofs. What happens if there is already a `sshfs` `/mnt/hostname` mounted there?

Comment: `/mnt` and `/net` are different directories and `sshfs` and `NFS` are different protocols. Nothing particular would happen if you use both methods to access the same shared directory. That would gave you to different paths to the same data.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say: What happens if there is an existing `sshfs` `/net/host` mounted and autofs wants to mount `host`'s NFS directories?

Comment: You can't have both sshfs and NFS configured to handle the same mount directory. You have to select different ones in the `auto_master` file.