# Autofs: /nfs-dir

Tags: nfs, autofs

At my university we had autofs set up so that you could:

```
cd /nfs/fqdn.of.some.nfs.server/share
```

and it would automount the nfs server+share as if root had done:

```
mount -t nfs fqdn.of.some.nfs.server:share /nfs/fqdn.of.some.nfs.server/share
```

It was extremely useful because you could then simply symlink to a dir in `/nfs/fqdn.of.some.nfs.server/share/sub/dir`.

I am thinking it must be the simplest autofs configuration, but I cannot find that config anywhere.

How do I configure autofs to do that?

Comment: sounds to me like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359151/117549

Comment: It is the configuration, I am looking for. I know what it is used for, but I am missing the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/auto.master:

```
/nfs    -hosts
```

Then restart autofs:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/autofs stop
sudo /etc/init.d/autofs start
```