# Autofs: /sshfs-dir

Tags: sshfs, autofs

The solution to having a dynamic `/nfs` dir proved to be extremely simple: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584475/2972

I am wondering if I can do the same for sshfs.

Let us assume that I can run:

```
sshfs remote.server: /sshfs/remote.server
```

without entering passphase (I use `ssh-agent`).

Is it possible for me to make an `sshfs.autofs` config that will run this no matter what `remote.server` I enter?

So that no matter the `remote.server` this would work:

```
cd /sshfs/remote.server/dir-on-remote.server
```

as long as the manual `sshfs remote.server: /sshfs/remote.server` would work.

The only answers I have been able to find lists the exact servers to use. So if I want to use those solutions, I need to know the servers in advance.

I can see the use of that, but I would (just like with nfs) prefer a config, where I do not have the know the servers in advance, and which will use the login config from `~/.ssh/config` - just like `sshfs` does when run manually.

I will be using this from my personal computer, so it is not a big risk if other users on my personal computer can see the password or can access the files as me.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294965/integration-of-afuse-user-level-automounter-with-sshfs-as-a-systemd-service-spaw/528699#528699  Basically same question with slightly different words

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use `afuse`:

```
afuse -o mount_template="sshfs %r:/ %m" -o unmount_template="fusermount -u -z %m" /sshfs
```

It does not use autofs, but it seems to work.